# Swift class cast fails while casting AnyObject to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: class, swift, nsmutablearray, classcastexception

```
var fetchEachStory = Firebase(url: "\(self.individualStoryUrl)\(eachStory)")

// Read data and react to changes
fetchEachStory.observeEventType(.Value) {
    snapshot in
    let storyDetails = snapshot.value as NSMutableDictionary?
    let score = storyDetails!["score"] as Int?
    var thisStory = eachStory
    if score? > self.minSetScore {
        self.showStories[thisStory] = storyDetails
    }              
}
```

While Assigning `Snapshot.value` to story details, it fails some times saying:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
let storyDetails = snapshot.value as NSMutableDictionary?
```

fails if `snapshot.value` is not an `NSMutableDictionary`.  It is better to use a conditional cast `as?` along with optional binding `if let` to make sure you only proceed if `snapshot.value` is the type you expect.  The same is true for `score` being an `Int`.

According to [the Firebase Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html#//api/name/value):

> value
>
> Returns the contents of this data snapshot as native types.
>
> @property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) id value Return Value The data
>   as a native object.
>
> Discussion Returns the contents of this data snapshot as native types.
>
> Data types returned: * NSDictionary * NSArray * NSNumber (also
>   includes booleans) * NSString
>
> Declared In FDataSnapshot.h

So you should be checking for `NSDictionary` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`.

I recommend:

```
// Read data and react to changes
fetchEachStory.observeEventType(.Value) {
    snapshot in
    if let storyDetails = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
        // We know snapshot.value was non-nil and it is an NSDictionary.
        if let score = storyDetails["score"] as? Int {
            // We know "score" is a valid key in the dictionary and that its
            // type is Int.
            var thisStory = eachStory
            if score > self.minSetScore {
                self.showStories[thisStory] = storyDetails
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }              
}
```

Comment: Did try try that. It will still fail with `as?` if  `snapshot == nil` , so before even checking `snapshot.value` , i should had checked if snapshot is nil with 'exists()` method provide by fireBase

Comment: @sapy, had you tried my previous suggestion? Or were you just guessing that it would fail?  `snapshot.exists()` tells you if `snapshot.value` is non-nil.  You don't have to check for that explicitly if you use optional binding because `if let storyDetails = snapshot.value` will just skip the `then` block if `snapshot.value` is `nil`.  It won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug , It's more to do with FireBase FDataSnapshot , Should check if snapshot is nil , with snapshot.exists()

```
var fetchEachStory = Firebase(url:"\(self.individualStoryUrl)\(eachStory)")
            // Read data and react to changes
            fetchEachStory.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
                snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists(){
                    let storyDetails = snapshot.value as NSDictionary?
                    let score = storyDetails!["score"] as Int?
                    var thisStory = eachStory
                    if score? > self.minSetScore{
                        self.showStories[thisStory] = storyDetails
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            })
```